# Strange associative array behaviour in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I execute below code on chrome console then, I got answer as associative array:

```
var arr= [];
var i = 1;
for(var j = 1; j < 3; j++)
    arr[j]=j;console.log(arr);
```

Ans : `[1: 1, 2: 2]`

But when i execute using node: `[ , 1, 2 ]`

Why there is so difference? As far as i know both are using v8.

Comment: why associative? its a normal array

Answer (score 5):

Firefox says

```
Array [ <1 empty slot>, 1, 2 ]
```

IE Edge says

```
[object Array][undefined, 1, 2]
```

and, they're all correct

Chrome is simply NOT reporting the empty index 0

Node is showing index 0 is empty

Firefox is telling you exactly what's happening

Try this:

```
var arr= [];var i = 1; for(var j = 1; j < 3; j++) arr[j*3]=j+3;console.log(arr);
```

Firefox:

```
Array [ <3 empty slots>, 4, <2 empty slots>, 5 ]
```

Node

```
[ , , , 4, , , 5 ]
```

IE Edge

```
[object Array][undefined, undefined, undefined, 4, undefined, undefined, 5]
```

Chrome

```
[3: 4, 6: 5]
```

Comment: What is the reason for such a weird behaviour?

Comment: @tehect *Weird*? Clarity for me. Much easier than reading IE Edge's

Comment: It's not weird. Console is not part of the ecmascript standard, how sparse arrays are logged to the console is implementation dependant ... don't worry about it, all those arrays will behave identically

Comment: try `var arr=[]; arr[1000000] = 1;console.log(arr);` - the best output is chrome, firefox tries, bless it, IE gives up, and node ... still going :D

Comment: @raghavendra hurrah for Chrome's `console.log` superiority

Comment: i am using canary for this arr = [,2,3] it is  displaying like this [undefined × 1, 2, 3]

Comment: @raghavendra chrome is trying to emulate a superior browser, google need to throw more money and time further optimising `console.log` implementation

Comment: for arr = [ , , , 4, , , 5 ] output [undefined × 3, 4, undefined × 2, 5]

Comment: yes i see some good feature coming up in canary not even in firefox

Comment: @RGraham I havn't worked on Edge. So should I consider node output as standard?

Comment: @tehect they are ALL different, mozilla, chrome, IE, node ... there is no standard as there doesn't need to be. `console.log` is a debugging tool